# Factory Girl Rails 4 association works in console, but not through Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, factory-bot

I have a Rails 4 application with a series of associations:  Posts have_many Reviews, Reviews have_one Assumption.  I have set up Factories to generate Reviews with Assumptions:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :review do
    association :post, factory: :post
    ...fields...

    factory :review_with_assumption do
      after(:create) do |review|
        FactoryGirl.create(:assumption, assumable: review)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The following works perfectly in the console:

```
post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
rev = FactoryGirl.create(:review_with_assumption, post: post)
rev.assumption.valid?
 => true
post.reviews.first.assumption.valid?
 => true
```

And all the fields are exactly as they are set in my Factory definitions -- for example, each Assumption includes a 'score' of 6.  However, when I use the following Cucumber steps, the Review is created but its Assumption is not:

```
Given(/^the post "(.*?)"'s review "(.*?)" has an assumption$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, name: arg1)
  rev = FactoryGirl.create(:review_with_assumption, name: arg2, post: post)
end
Then(/^I should see the "(.*?)" review assumption's score$/) do |arg2|
  rev = Review.find_by_name(arg2)
  page.should have_content rev.assumption.score
end
```

So I get an error that looks like:

```
And I should see the "Test Rev" review assumption's score
      undefined method `score' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The page content it is trying to render works perfectly in the browser if I input everything manually.  Why doesn't it also work through Factory Girl and Cucumber?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "review" record whose name is "arg1". Instead, according to your definition, the one having name as "arg1" is the `post` record.

Comment: I apologize--those variable names were confusing and have been corrected.  It is actually the 'arg2' name being used to create the Review record.

Comment: @thusson, that's fine :) But, still, args problem. If this is your exact code, you used `arg1` in second block as `rev = Review.find_by_name(arg1)`. `Then` is another context, arg1 doesn't live here so you can't use it, and rev is nil of course. The fix is to define `arg1` as an instance variable `@arg1` so that you can access it later in other blocks of this test

Comment: Yes, you're right -- corrected again, more apologies :)  But the issue is that the test finds the Review just fine, but it does not have an Assumption associated with it.  Thanks for all your help, sorry for the snafus.